# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

Появляется ошибка компиляции: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'(line 19)`. Использую Win10 x64, IDE PyCharm Community 2017.3, Python 3.6.4

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 31 12:03:43 2017
Лабораторная работа №1 - ИССЛЕДОВАНИЕ РАБОТЫ ПИ-РЕГУЛЯТОРА
Программа расчета траектории изменения скорости робота, движущегося по прямой
от текущей начальной скорости до заданной круизной скорости,
===== устройство управления - ПИ- регулятор с коэффициентами kP, kI =====
u[i] = kP*err[i] + kI*sumerr[i]*dt
u[i] - управление (сила разгона или торможения, деленная на массу тела)
err[i] = Vdir - v[i]  # - ошибка управления (рассогласование в i-й момент)
===== система управления описывается итерационным (разностным) уравнением  =====
V[i+1] = v[i] + (u[i] - kc*v[i])*dt/m   , м/с
v[i] - скорость робота в i-й момент времени t[i+1]= t[i]+dt, с
kc - коэффициент сопротивления среды
m - масса робота (кг)

@author: dcyrils
"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
#
# 1. АНАЛИЗ РАБОТЫ ПИ-РЕГУЛЯТОРА при ЗАДАННЫХ ЗНАЧЕНИЯХ
def cruizCtrl(kP, kI = 0.1, kc = 0.3, Vdir = 30, Umax = 100):
    ## 'kP' - коэффициент пропорционального регулятора
    ## 'kI' - коэффициент интегрального регулятора
    V0 = 0
    m = 100
    dt = 1
    maxT = 400
    ind = list(range(maxT))
    Umin = -Umax
    T = ind*dt
    err = 0
    sumerr = 0
    v = []
    v.append(V0)
    for i in range(maxT):
        err = Vdir - v[i]
        sumerr += err
        u = kP*err + kI*sumerr*dt
        if u > Umax: u = Umax
        if u < Umin: u = Umin
        v.append(v[i] + (u - kc*v[i])*dt/m)
    ## необходимо вернуть data.frame - в 1-м столбце - вектор времен,
    ## во 2-м - вектор скоростей data.frame(T,v)
    df_Tv = pd.DataFrame(v[:maxT], index=T, columns=['v'])
    df_Tv.index.name = 'T'
    return df_Tv
#
dV = 0.1
res = cruizCtrl(kP=3, kI=0.3, kc=2, Vdir=25, Umax=200)

print(res.head())

# PLOTs
Vdir=25
plt.rcParams['font.fantasy'] = 'Arial', 'Times New Roman', 'Tahoma', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Courier'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'fantasy'
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(res)
a1 = pd.Series(Vdir, index=res.index)
ax.plot(a1, color='red')
a2 = pd.Series(Vdir-dV*10, index=res.index)
ax.plot(a2, 'k--', color='green')
a3 = pd.Series(Vdir+dV*10, index=res.index)
ax.plot(a3, 'k--', color='green')
plt.title('Изменение скорости: ПИ-регулятор', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel(u'Время, с', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(u'Скорость, м/с', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
#
# 2. ИССЛЕДУЕМ ПИ-РЕГУЛЯТОР
## ПРограмма расчета времени достижения заданной точности по скорости
## tv - data.frame, содержащий время и скорость
## Vdir, dV - это заданная скорость и точность достижения скорости
##
def getTime(tv, Vdir, dV):
    i = len(tv) - 1
    while((abs(Vdir - tv.v[i]) < dV) & (i>1)) : i -= 1
    return tv.index[i]
## необходимо вернуть время, начиная с которого скорость отклонялась от заданной
## меньше, чем на dV
tlim = getTime(res, Vdir, dV)
#
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(res[50:])
a1 = pd.Series(Vdir, index=res.index[50:])
ax.plot(a1, color='red')
a2 = pd.Series(Vdir-dV*2, index=res.index[50:])
ax.plot(a2, 'k--', color='green')
a3 = pd.Series(Vdir+dV*2, index=res.index[50:])
ax.plot(a3, 'k--', color='green')
ax.plot([tlim,tlim], [Vdir-10, Vdir+10], color='brown')
plt.title('Изменение скорости: ПИ-регулятор kP=3, kI=0.3', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel(u'Время, с', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(u'Скорость, м/с', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
#
# РАСЧЕТ ТРАЕКТОРИИ СКОРОСТИ при ВЫБРАННЫХ ЗНАЧЕНИЯХ ПАРАМЕТРОВ ПИ-регулятора:
kP1 = 4.7; kI1 = 0.1
res1 = cruizCtrl(kP1, kI1, kc=2, Vdir=25, Umax=200)
# РАСЧЕТ ВРЕМЕНИ ДОСТИЖЕНИЯ ЗАДАННОЙ ТОЧНОСТИ и ВЫВОД ГРАФИКА
tlim1 = getTime(res1, Vdir, dV)
#
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(res1[50:])
a1 = pd.Series(Vdir, index=res.index[50:])
ax.plot(a1, color='red')
a2 = pd.Series(Vdir-dV*2, index=res.index[50:])
ax.plot(a2, 'k--', color='green')
a3 = pd.Series(Vdir+dV*2, index=res.index[50:])
ax.plot(a3, 'k--', color='green')
ax.plot([tlim1,tlim1], [Vdir-4, Vdir+4], color='brown')
plt.title('Изменение скорости: ПИ-регулятор kP=4.7, kI=0.1', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel(u'Время, с', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(u'Скорость, м/с', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
#
# 3.    ИССЛЕДУЕМ ПОРЯДОК И СКОРОСТЬ СХОДИМОСТИ
# ПРОГРАММА РАСЧЕТА ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНОСТИ ОТНОШЕНИЯ:
def getCC(v, Vdir, p):
    vf, pf = [], []
    cc = [1.]
    i = 0
    while v[i] < Vdir-0.1 :
        i += 1
        vf.append(v[i])
    numv = len(vf)
    istep = list(range(numv))*len(p)
    for n in range(len(p)):
        for m in range(numv):
            pf.append(p[n])
    vf = vf*len(p)
    for i in range(1, len(vf)):
        cc.append(abs(Vdir - vf[i])/abs(Vdir - vf[i-1])**pf[i])
    ## необходимо вернуть data.frame - в 1-м столбце - вектор номеров шагов,
    ## во 2-м - стабилизируемая последовательность,
    ## в 3-м - фактор разных споледовательностей (при разных значениях p)
    ## data.frame(istep,cc,pf)
    df_cc = pd.DataFrame({'istep' : pd.Series(istep),
                          'cc' : pd.Series(cc),
                          'pf' : pd.Series(pf)} )
    return df_cc
#
#c = [1., 1.1, 1.2]
c = [0.4, 1, 1.6]
ccframe = getCC(res1.v, Vdir, c)
b = int(len(ccframe) / len(c))
#
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(ccframe.istep[1:b], ccframe.cc[1:b], color='red')
ax.plot(ccframe.istep[b+1:b+b], ccframe.cc[b+1:b+b], 'k--', color='green')
ax.plot(ccframe.istep[b+b+1:], ccframe.cc[b+b+1:], 'k.', color='brown')
plt.title('Оценка порядка и скорости сходимости', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel(u'istep', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel(u'cc', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
#
order = [1.05]
ccframe = getCC(res1.v, Vdir, order)
print('velocity = ', 1/ccframe.cc.mean())
```

> `C:\Users\myPC\PycharmProjects\myPythonApps\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>
>   C:/Users/myPC/PycharmProjects/myPythonApps/PI-regulator Traceback
>   (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/myPC/PycharmProjects/myPythonApps/PI-regulator", line 19, in
>   <module> import pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'pandas'`

---

Сделал:

```
C:\Windows\System32>pip install pandas
```

Pandas установился:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\mypc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2 in с:\users\mypc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages     (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.0 in c:\users\mypc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in c:\users\mypc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\mypc\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas)

C:\Windows\System32>
```

Но код в PyCharm все равно не компилируется:

```
C:\Users\myPC\PycharmProjects\myPythonApps\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/myPC/PycharmProjects/myPythonApps/PI-regulator
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/myPC/PycharmProjects/myPythonApps/PI-regulator", line 19, in <module>
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Ну так установи. По умолчанию его нет.

Comment: можешь выложить инструкцию по установке?

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае у вас не установлен модуль `pandas`.

---

**1 способ установить**

Вы можете открыть консоль и задать команду `pip install pandas`.

---

**2 способ установить**
В `PyCharm` зайти в настройки а именно `Settings -> Project -> Interpreter` нажать на `+` после чего в поиске напечатать название модуля для скачивания
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**3 способ установить**

скачать `.whl` с [оф сайта](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.21.1/#files), а после скачивания установитть командой
`pip install C:/some-dir/pandas-0.21.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl`
Вместо `C:/some-dir/pandas-0.21.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` та директория где хранится `.whl` файл и его название