# проблема c установкой

Tags: python, pygame

Как установить PyGame в Windows?

Comment: [можете попробовать по такому же принципу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/788268/255866)

Comment: Как пробовали устанавливать?

Answer (score 1):

Меню пуск -> Поиск -> "cmd"

Туда вводишь: 
pip install pygame

Если возникнут проблемы, тогда вот расширенный мануал 
https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/