# Ошибка при запуске кода на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

[image: Выдаёт ошибку при запуске кода]
Я откатился по советам до версии 3.6 с 3.7, установил telebot заново запускаю код в PyCharm и тут вот такая вот ошибки, аж 3!

> ```
> D:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/python
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, 
>    in _run_module_as_main" +__main__", mod_spec)
>   File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, 
>     in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
>   File "D:/python\__main__.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import telebot
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'
> ```

Подскадите пожалуйста как решить?

Comment: можете попробовать его установить [по такому же принципу как в данном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788178/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas/788268#788268)

Comment: Похоже, в `D:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe` не установлен telebot

Comment: Та не телебот стоит, а что значат эти две ошибки выше

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, 
   in _run_module_as_main" +__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, 
    in _run_code exec(code, run_globals

Comment: это одна ошибка и она заключается в том что у вас не установлен `telebot` ну или он просто не опознается `PyCharm`

Comment: Мне стоит перекачать телебот ? Или pycharm по новой скачать ?

Comment: можете попробовать тот вариант которыйя вам пример в первом коментарии, там схожая ситуация только с `pandas`

Comment: Мне просто попробовать установить телебот через pycharm так как с помощью консоли я уже устанавливал, и если не выйдет перекачать pycharm ?

Comment: Там 3 варианта установки попробуйте, если один не получился попробуйте другой по моему все достаточно очевидно

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас установлен telebot, то проблема в том что он не видит его. Это происходит из-за отсутствия доступа к самому телеботу

При создании проекта сделайте следующее

[image: Попытайтесь так]

В случае если это не сработает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего `telebot` не установлен в текущем `venv'e`, откройте терминал, перейдите в папку с проектом, напишите `venv\Scripts\activate` и затем `pip install pytelegrambotapi`