# Установка библиотек на PyCharm

Tags: python, библиотеки, pycharm

***Правильно ли я понимаю: 'Когда я устанавливаю библиотеку через PyCharm, то она устанавливается только в проект'?***

Если через cmd то на весь пк сразу?
Просто у меня скрипт через пайчарм работал, а чтобы через лкм по .py на рабочем столе нет. Пришлось в cmd устанавливать библиотеки, так как скрипт выдавал ошибку, не найдена библиотека.

Comment: Нет она устанавливается на весь компьютер, только библиотека в файлах pycharm их можно в pycharm обновлять в настройках.

Comment: похожий вопрос [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788178/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pandas/788268#788268)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы в создали [виртуальное окружение](https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-17-virtual-envs/) для проекта, и в настройках проекта указан интерпретатор из этого виртуального окружения, то библиотека устанавливается локально, в этом виртуальном окружении. В настройках проекта можно указать использовать системный интерпретатор Python, а не Python из виртуального окружения, тогда и библиотеки будут устанавливаться для системного Python.

Пример, выбран общесистемный интерпретатор:

[image: Общесистемный интерпретатор]

Интерпретатор из виртуального окружения (обратите внимание на зеленую букву V на значке интерпретатора):

[image: Виртуальное окружение]

Также, если установлено несколько интерпретаторов (интерпретаторы разных версий, anaconda, pypy, и т.д.), может оказаться, что в настройках проекта указан один, а при запуске вне проекта ("с рабочего стола") запускается другим интерпретатором. Соответственно, и библиотеки для разных интерпретаторов ставятся независимо друг от друга.

При разработке в Pycharm удобнее использовать для проекта отдельное виртуальное окружение с ограниченным набором библиотек. При использовании системного интерпретатора Pycharm может очень надолго уходить в переиндексацию доступных модулей. Если сделать окружение с 1-3 нужными дополнительными библиотеками, то индексация происходит намного быстрее. Для запуска "снаружи" можно сделать пусковой файл (bat под windows, sh под linux), который будет активировать окружение, а потом запускать саму программу.

Comment: Спасибо, прямо в точку!

Comment: так же можно установить библиотеки через командную строку `pycharm`

Answer (score 0):

Если устанавливать через терминал внутри PyCharm`а, то тогда библиотека устанавливается внутри проекта и не более. Если устанавливать через cmd вашей ОС, то библиотека устанавливается на ВСЮ систему и используется везде.