# Выводятся библиотеки которые я не скачивал в pycharm linux

Tags: python, linux, elementary-os

Сразу извините за возможно глупый вопрос, но я новичок в linux и хотел бы разобраться

**Вопрос:**

У меня в pycharm выводятся библиотеки, которые я не вызывал, и я хотел спросить: это библиотеки системного питона linux? Если да, то как можно сделать так, чтобы они не вызывались при запуске нового проекта? Или это обязательные библиотеки для проекта? Стоят 2-е версии python (системный python3.8 и python3.10)

Использую Elementary os 6

**Вот библиотеки:**

Brlapi  0.7.0   Click   7.0 8.0.3

Pillow  7.0.0   8.4.0

PyGObject   3.36.0  3.42.0

PyJWT   1.7.1   2.3.0

PyNaCl  1.3.0   1.4.0

PyYAML  5.3.1   6.0

SecretStorage   2.3.1   3.3.1

blinker 1.4 1.4

certifi 2019.11.28  2021.10.8

chardet 3.0.4   4.0.0

command-not-found   0.3

cryptography    2.8 35.0.0

dbus-python 1.2.16  1.2.18

defer   1.0.6   1.0.4

distro  1.4.0   1.6.0

distro-info 0.23ubuntu1 1.0

entrypoints 0.3 0.3

html5lib    1.0.1   1.1

httplib2    0.14.0  0.20.1

idna    2.8 3.3

keyring 18.0.1  23.2.1

language-selector   0.1

launchpadlib    1.10.13 1.10.15.1

lazr.restfulclient  0.14.2  0.14.4

lazr.uri    1.0.3   1.0.6

louis   3.12.0  1.3

lxml    4.5.0   4.6.3

netifaces   0.10.4  0.11.0

oauthlib    3.1.0   3.1.1

olefile 0.46    0.46

onboard 1.4.1

pexpect 4.6.0   4.8.0

pip 20.0.2  21.3.1

pycairo 1.16.2  1.20.1

pymacaroons 0.13.0  0.13.0

python-apt  2.0.0-ubuntu0.20.04.6-elementary6-ubuntu6.1 0.7.8

pyxdg   0.26    0.27

reportlab   3.5.34  3.6.2

requests    2.22.0  2.26.0

requests-unixsocket 0.2.0   0.2.0

setuptools  45.2.0  58.3.0

simplejson  3.16.0  3.17.5

six 1.14.0  1.16.0

soupsieve   1.9.5   2.2.1

ubuntu-advantage-tools  27.2

ubuntu-drivers-common   0.0.0

ufw 0.36

unattended-upgrades 0.1

urllib3 1.25.8  1.26.7

wadllib 1.3.3   1.3.6

webencodings    0.5.1   0.5.1

wheel   0.34.2  0.37.0

xkit    0.0.0

Comment: Наличие `command-not-found` в списке намекает, что это всё установилось вместе с системой

Answer (score 2):

Всё я разобрался. Дело в том, что я указывал общий интерпретатор Python. А надо указывать тот интерпретатор, который указывается в виртуальном окружении самого проекта. Вот похожий вопрос и ответ на него, который мне помог:

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026636/Установка-библиотек-на-pycharm](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026636/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pycharm)